# Javascript Promise/Then losing scope

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jquery-deferred, promise, q

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
I have a promise that is losing local variable scope when the result is returned.
I need the id value available when the deferred call finishes:

```
getChildren:function(id){
    service.getChildren(id)
   .then(function(result){
        var parentId = id  //null
        return result
    })
   .fail(function (error) {
        log.error(error);
    })
}
```

Comment: The code snippet alone looks correct. Without more information I doubt we will be able to help you. A http://www.jsfiddle.net/ demo would be great.

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/qUHze/

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting `result` to be returned from a call to `getChildren()`?

If so then (assuming `service.getChildren()` returns a jQuery Promise), the code needs to modified slightly the such that `.getChildren()` returns a *promise* of delivering `result` later :

This can be achieved as follows :

```
getChildren:function(id) {
    return service.getChildren(id).done(function(result) {
        //here do something generic with `result`
    }).fail(function (error) {
        log.error(error);
    });
}
```

And `.getChildren()` might be called as follows :

```
myObj.getChildren(myID).done(function(result) {
    //here do something specific with `result`
});
```

Note: The extra power of `.then()` appears not to be required here but would be necessary if you wanted to promise delivery of something other than `result`.